# What's a good coding style for reading different bits of data from a binary file in C?

Tags: c, coding-style, binaryfiles

I'm novice programmer and am writing a simple wav-player in C as a pet project. Part of the file loading process requires reading specific data (sampling rate, number of channels,...) from the file header.
Currently what I'm doing is similar to this:

1. Scan for a sequence of bytes and skip past it
2. Read 2 bytes into variable a
3. Check value and return on error
4. Skip 4 bytes
5. Read 4 bytes into variable b
6. Check value and return on error

...and so on. (code see: https://github.com/qgi/Player/blob/master/Importer.c)

I've written a number of helper functions to do the scanning/skipping/reading bit. Still I'm repeating the reading, checking, skipping part several times, which doesn't seem to be neither very effective nor very smart. It's not a real issue for my project, but as this seems to be quite a common task when handling binary files, I was wondering:
Is there some kind of a pattern on how to do this more effectively with cleaner code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most often, people define structs (often with something like `#pragma pack(1)` to assure against padding) that matches the file's structures. They then read data into an instance of that with something like `fread`, and use the values from the struct.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of structs! Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest option that I've come across is the `scanf`-like function `unpack` presented by Kernighan & Pike on [page 219 of *The Practice of Programming*](http://books.google.com/books?id=to6M9_dbjosC&pg=PA219), which can be used like

```
// assume we read the file header into buf
// and the header consists of magic (4 bytes), type (2) and length (4).
// "l" == 4 bytes (long)
// "s" == 2 bytes (short)
unpack(buf, "lsl", &magic, &type, &length);
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a decent and flexible solution!

Comment: @qgi: this is the most portable solution that I've ever come across and it's great for both binary file parsing and network programming. (It also works with `struct`'s, btw.)

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency using a buffer of say size 4096 to read into and then doing your parsing on the data in the buffer would be more efficient, and ofcource doing a single scan parsing where you only go forward is most efficient.